# Как добавить пару ключ-значение в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Меня очень давно мучает этот вопрос. Допустим, у меня есть словарь:

```
d = {'format': 'video', 'abr': '320'}
```

Я хочу чтобы в словарь добавилась еще одна пара:

```
'height': '720'
```

И в результате должно получится:

```
d = {'format': 'video', 'abr': '320', 'height': '720'}
```

Что я должен сделать? Может это что-то вроде `d.add('height': '720')`?

Comment: d['height'] =  '720'

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary/

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, не думал что это решается таким странным способом

Answer (score 6, accepted):

самый простой вариант:

```
In [146]: d['height'] = '720'
```

альтернативный вариант, позволяющий добавить сразу несколько элементов:

```
In [149]: d.update(dict(height='720', blah='blah-blah'))

In [150]: d
Out[150]: {'format': 'video', 'abr': '320', 'height': '720', 'blah': 'blah-blah'}
```

Answer (score 3):

***Код:***

```
d = {
    'format': 'video',
    'abr': '320',
}

d['height'] = '720'  # или "d.update({'height': '720'})"
print(d)
```

***stdout:***

```
{'format': 'video', 'abr': '320', 'height': '720'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
d = {'format': 'video', 'abr': '320'}
d['height'] = '720'
```

В отличии от списков,если попробовать присвоить какое-нибудь значение несуществующему элементу,то этот элемент будет создан и получит значение которое вы присваивали.Со списками же такая махинация вызовет исключение!